# Get the attachment URL on single.php

Tags: attachments, media-library

i've been trying to get the attachment URL on single.php, so far this code gets the DIRECT LINK to the image;

```
<?php

if ( $attachments = get_children( array(
'post_type' => 'attachment',
'post_mime_type'=>'image',
'numberposts' => 1,
'post_status' => null,
'post_parent' => $post->ID
)));
foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
echo '<a target="_blank" href="' . wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment->ID ) . '">Download Full Size</a>';
}

?>
```

but instead i want the attachment URL, PLEASE HELP!

Comment: Do you mean `get_permalink( $attachment->ID ) )`?

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_get_permalink()

Comment: Of course, such a function doesn’t exists … and no one said it does. :)

Comment: If something doesn’t work look for [debug data](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `the_attachment_link` returns an HTML link, so use this code:

```
if ( $attachments = get_children( array(
    'post_type'      => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'numberposts'    => 1,
    'post_status'    => null,
    'post_parent'    => $post->ID
) ) );
foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
    echo wp_get_attachment_link( 
        $attachment->ID, '' , true, false, 'Link to image attachment' 
    );
}
```

Here I'm passing 5 parameters to function `wp_get_attachment_link()`

- First parameter is `$attachment->ID` to get attachment ID
- Second parameter `''` says not to print image
- Third parameter `true` links to attachment page
- Fourth `false` parameter tells not to print media parameter
- The last one is the text you'd like to appear as a link

Comment: This function gets the attachment as thumbnail and linked to Direct link (.jpg), i want the link in HTML format to attachment page so where i can maximize my images to view larger

Comment: hey, updated answer to print link to attachment page with text.

Comment: set the `$permalink` parameter to true to return link to attachment page instead of file.

Comment: :D Problem Solved! Thanks alot amit for helping me out :)

Answer (score 2):

You’re looking for: [`get_attachment_link( $attachment->ID )`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_attachment_link).

---

As toscho suggested in his comment, you can also use the generic [`get_permalink()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink) function which internally calls `get_attachment_link()`.

Comment: Tried this one but it gives me "Missing Attachment"

Comment: If no attachment can be found, the function displays the string `Missing Attachment`.

Comment: Attachment is there, if you see above code that i posted shows the Direct link to the image that has been attached in the POST

Answer (score 0):

Great! changing the lines

```
'post_mime_type'=>'image', 
  echo wp_get_attachment_link( $attachment-  >ID, '' , true, false, 'Link to image attachment' );
```

to

```
 'post_mime_type'=>'application', 
  echo wp_get_attachment_link( $attachment->ID, '' , false, false, 'Download File' );
```

I could link a direct download from PDF File attached to post

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the code that can able to pull exact URL of corresponding image from media and found this thread. I tweaked it little bit

Here is the code that I used to pull image for PIN IT button.....

```
<?php

if ( $attachments = get_children( array(
   'post_type' => 'attachment',
   'post_mime_type'=>'image',
   'numberposts' => 1,
   'post_status' => null,
   'post_parent' => $post->ID
)));

foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
   echo '' . wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment->ID ) . '';
}

?>
```