# Creating a gallery custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, gallery

Hi I was wondering if it is possible to create a custom post type called "Gallery" where i only upload photos and ad captions and when i post it, it post as a gallery. Also when it shows on the homepage it shows as "View Photos" instead of read more, and goes straight to the gallery page.

Also i want to be able to add taxonomies such as "Tv Show" so it will be like this

mysite.com/photos/tv-show-name/photo-gallery

The post below didn't help me, i tried that plugin and it didn't work for me it didn't go to a gallery it went to a single post page with nothing on it.

[Creating Photo Gallery System with Custom Post Type](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/57480/creating-photo-gallery-system-with-custom-post-type)

Comment: Why not to use Post Formats, http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Formats

Comment: I didn't know about that i will test this out to see if it works

Comment: I don't understand that it doesn't work for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I show different text for linking to gallery posts ?

YES, Here's how to do it, put this where you want to output text as - readmore/view photos, depending on theme or way you're generating these text we can use filter to change it as per custom post type.

```
<?php 
echo '<a href="'.the_permalink().'">';
if ( 'gallery' == get_post_type() ) {
    echo 'View Photos';
} else {
    echo 'Read More';
}
echo '</a>';
?>
```

> Custom template for Custome post type

You can configure your blog to use [different template for custom post type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Type_Templates) by creating a template with slug `single-gallery.php` where gallery is custom post type slug.

> **Update**- To show images as gallery on single post (from this [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/60439/17968))

Add the following code to your themes `single.php` to show the attached images(full) beneath the post content, And the condition will check for custom post type - `gallery`.

```
<?php

if ( 'gallery' == get_post_type() ) { //condition to show gallery on post type - gallery

    if ( $attachments = get_children( array(
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'post_mime_type'=>'image',   //return all image attachment only
        'numberposts' => -1,   //get all the attachments
        'post_parent' => $post->ID
    )));

    foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
        // you can customize the oputput
        echo wp_get_attachment_link( $attachment->ID, 'full' , false, false, '' );
        echo '<span class="img_cap">'.$attachment->post_excerpt.'</span>';

    }
}

?>
```

Read the codex page for more information - [wp_get_attachment_link#Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_link#Parameters)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4367/discussion-between-amit-and-terrell-anderson)